# Spring Bean Dependency Missing but Log and Debug state it was instantiated

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot 1.3.4.RELEASE with Spring 4.2.6.RELEASE.

I have the following class:

```
@Component
class ServerRunner implements Runnable {
```

With Constructor:

```
 @Autowired
  ServerRunner(@Value(HEARTBEAT_SECONDS) final long secondsBetweenHeartbeats,
               final ServerSocket socket,
               final PlayerRepository playerRepository,
               final DeckProcessor deckProcessor) {
    this.serverSocket = socket;
    this.maintainer = new Maintainer(secondsBetweenHeartbeats);
    this.playerRepository = playerRepository;
    final ExecutorService executorService = newCachedThreadPool();
    executorService.execute(this);
    this.running = true;

    this.deckProcessor = deckProcessor;
    executorService.execute(maintainer);
  }
```

When I start my Application, it can not find the Dependency `DeckProcessor`.

```
@Component
class DeckProcessor extends AbstractPlayerProcessor {
  private final DeckRepository repository;

  @Autowired(required = true)
  DeckProcessor(final DeckRepository repository) {
    super(QUERY_DECKS);
    this.repository = repository;
  }
```

The following Exception is thrown:

```
  23:12:42 ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'serverRunner' defined in file [GameServer\arml-server\build\classes\main\com\arml\services\ServerRunner.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 3 of type [com.arml.services.DeckProcessor]: No qualifying bean of type [com.arml.services.DeckProcessor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.arml.services.DeckProcessor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) ~[spring-boot-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar:1.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar:1.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar:1.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar:1.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.arml.ArmlServer.main(ArmlServer.java:21) [main/:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.arml.services.DeckProcessor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 17 more
```

But the Log clearly states:

```
16:44:05 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean deckProcessor
16:44:05 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean deckProcessor
16:44:05 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'deckProcessor' via constructor to bean named 'deckRepository'
16:44:05 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'deckProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
16:44:05 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'deckProcessor'
```

Both classes reside in the same package.

What am I doing wrong? I've been debugging for hours and can not find a solution.

SpringBoot App:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.arml.persistence.repositories")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@SpringBootApplication
public class ArmlServer {

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder()
        .web(false)
        .bannerMode(OFF)
        .sources(ArmlServer.class)
        .run(args);
  }
}
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ArmlConfiguration {
  private static final Base64.Decoder DECODER = getDecoder();

  @Bean
  public ServerSocket armlSslSocket(@Value("${arml.server.bind-address}") final String bindAddress,
                                    @Value("${arml.server.port}") final int port,
                                    @Value("${arml.ssl.password}") final String password)
      throws IOException {
    final String keyPass = new String(DECODER.decode(password), UTF_8);
    return createServerSocket(bindAddress, port, keyPass);
  }

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource(final DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties)
      throws PropertyVetoException {
    final ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClass(dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName());
    dataSource.setUser(dataSourceProperties.getUsername());
    dataSource.setPassword(new String(DECODER.decode(dataSourceProperties.getPassword()), UTF_8));
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(dataSourceProperties.getUrl());
    return dataSource;
  }
}
```

Edit:
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjdD5.png)

Edit2: I did try the suggestions by @Gemini Keith. The `ServerRunner` now looks like this (I've removed some constants/methods for brevity):

```
@Component
@DependsOn("deckProcessor")
class ServerRunner implements Runnable {    

  @Value(HEARTBEAT_SECONDS)
  private long secondsBetweenHeartbeats;
  private Maintainer maintainer;
  @Autowired
  private ServerSocket serverSocket;
  @Autowired
  private PlayerRepository playerRepository;
  @Autowired
  private DeckProcessor deckProcessor;

  ServerRunner() {
  }

  @PostConstruct
  void init() {
    this.maintainer = new Maintainer(secondsBetweenHeartbeats);
    final ExecutorService executorService = newCachedThreadPool();
    executorService.execute(this);
    this.running = true;

    executorService.execute(maintainer);
  }
```

But the exception remains:

```
07:12:36 ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverRunner': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.arml.services.DeckProcessor com.arml.services.ServerRunner.deckProcessor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.arml.services.DeckProcessor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) ~[spring-boot-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar:1.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar:1.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar:1.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar:1.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.arml.ArmlServer.main(ArmlServer.java:20) [main/:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.arml.services.DeckProcessor com.arml.services.ServerRunner.deckProcessor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.arml.services.DeckProcessor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.arml.services.DeckProcessor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 15 more
```

I also rechecked the Annotations and they are:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
```

The Constructor injection works once I remove the `deckProcessor`. This is really confusing!

Edit3:
I'm an idiot. The parameter should've had the interface type. After changing the constructor to:

```
  @Autowired
  ServerRunner(@Value(HEARTBEAT_SECONDS) final long secondsBetweenHeartbeats,
               final ServerSocket armlSslSocket,
               final PlayerRepository playerRepository,
               final Processor<ServerClientHandler> deckProcessor) {
    this.serverSocket = armlSslSocket;
    this.maintainer = new Maintainer(secondsBetweenHeartbeats);
    this.playerRepository = playerRepository;
    final ExecutorService executorService = newCachedThreadPool();
    executorService.execute(this);
    this.running = true;

    this.deckProcessor = deckProcessor;
    executorService.execute(maintainer);
  }
```

It works fine.

Comment: Add your project structure and also post the complete stacktrace..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a initialization dependency problem. Please try to use `@DependsOn` together with `@Component` on class `ServerRunner` as following:

```
@DependsOn(value = "deckProcessor")
@Component
```

`value` means the bean name of `DeckProcessor`, which is always `deckProcessor` by default. However, you can name it by specifying the name at `@Component(value = 'nameOfYourBean')`.

In your case, your constructor need autowire a `DeckProcessor`, which is too strict for instantiate a `ServerRunner` bean, which means a `DeckProcessor` bean must be there when a `ServerRunner` is being created. Otherwise, the `ServerRunner` could not be instantiated. However, you can initial the `ServerRunner` by create a `@PostConstruct` method and move the code from constructor into it. Such as:

```
@Value(HEARTBEAT_SECONDS)
long secondsBetweenHeartbeats;
@Autowired
ServerSocket socket;
@Autowired
PlayerRepository playerRepository;
@Autowired
DeckProcessor deckProcessor;
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
  this.serverSocket = socket;
  this.maintainer = new Maintainer(secondsBetweenHeartbeats);
  this.playerRepository = playerRepository;
  final ExecutorService executorService = newCachedThreadPool();
  executorService.execute(this);
  this.running = true;

  this.deckProcessor = deckProcessor;
  executorService.execute(maintainer);
}
```

At this point, spring can instantiate all beans and later continue initialize them one by one. It should work.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately, neither of your suggestions worked. The `init` method must be a no-arg method, so that didn't work at all. I did remove the arguments and made the fields non-final with an `@Autowired` Annotation, but it sill is unable to find the `deckProcessor`. I will update the Question.

Comment: Ok, you can @Autowired it as class member instead of arguments.

Comment: I did exactly that. And it didn't work either. :( I've updated the question.

Comment: Here are two solutions, one is `@DependsOn`, the other is `@PostConstruct`. Please remove `@DependsOn` annotation on class `ServerRunner` if you are using `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: If it still doesn't work and if you don't mind, please publish your project on github, it's should be useful.

Comment: That still doesn't work. But if I remove the `extends` it suddenly works. I also tried just implementing the underlying interface which also doesn't work. But if I do not extend/implement anything with `DeckProcessor`, it can be injected.

Comment: Ok, so what does `AbstractPlayerProcessor` do in this example? Is there any other annotations on it?

Comment: I'm an idiot. The parameter should've had the interface type. After changing it to `final Processor<ServerClientHandler> deckProcessor`
It works fine. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm sorry for not specifying the real point of this solution. If possible, please help to update my answer. Thanks in advance!